# Heroku: Pretending to be another domain?

Tags: heroku, proxy

First off, let me explain what I'm doing. I'm trying to build a website that replaces PokeVision, a service that  connects to Pokémon Go servers and maps it. 
Problem is, Niantic has blocked many popular hosting sites, including Heroku and Amazon. I use heroku.

Tldr; A server I'm trying to request and send data to is blocking my host, Heroku.

So... How would I pretend to be another domain? I'd say proxy but I'm not sure if that's the correct term in this case. Thank you so much!